# Compiling a flex.cc gives error

Tags: c++, c, gcc, flex-lexer

i was compiling a lex.yy.cc and it is giving me the following error: FlexLexer.h no such file or directory

I have tried to put this .h on the same file as the code persé, and it stills gives me the error, i tried all the following ways to compile it and the web is not giving me a clear answer to my problem:

g++ lex.yy.cc

g++ lex.yy.cc -lfl

g++ lex.yy.cc -lm

g++ lex.yy.cc -lfl -lm

gcc lex.yy.cc -lm

gcc lex.yy.cc

nothing happend, i really dont know what else to try, i have changed the enviroments variables a 100 times and doesnt work. Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

As @user2912836 stated try the `-I` command, I've run into the same problem before and its worked for me. 
More info on directory searching: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.4/gcc_3.html#SEC1s

Answer (score 0):

By "nothing happened", did you mean it was giving you the same error, or it just didn't output anything?

If it's the first case, I suggest you use the `-I` option to tell gcc where your headers file are.

If it's the second case, it probably compiled. See if there is an `a.out` file in your directory.

Comment: hi, i meant the second one, it is not compiling :( idk why

Comment: @RodolfoJoséMiquilarena Do you mean that after you pressed enter nothing showed up in the terminal? It probably compiled as `a.out`, which is the default output name for gcc if no `-o` option specified.